# EViews Maximum Likelihood Output, Coefficient C(3)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, inference, econometrics, eviews

I would like to estimate the following model in EViews using ML:

y_i = x0 + x1*beta_i + epsilon_i

I get three values as output: C(1), C(2) and C(3)

I think the meaning of C(3) is that it is the mean variance of the residual.

But I also get a standard error for C(3) as well as a p-value. My question is: What do these two signify precisely in this case? Do they mean that if p-value=0.000 the residual's variance is highly significant?

Thank you!